# Python types: multiple unpackings in first argument to Callable

Tags: python, python-typing, typing

**Abstract**

I'd like to have a decorator that calls a function `F`, and inserts the return values into the decorated method `M`. `M`'s parameters should be a (non-strict) superset of `F`'s.

**Description**

Here's a sample implementation

```py
def outer(F):
    def inner(M):
        @wraps(M)
        def aux(*args):
            res_F = F(*args)
            res_M = M(*args, *res_F)
            return res_M
        return aux
    return inner
```

and here's how you can use it

```py
def some_function(s: str, t: str) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    return (len(s), len(t))

@outer(some_function)
def some_method(s: str, t str, x: int, y: int):
    assert len(s) == x
    assert len(t) == y
```

How would I go about typing this?

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved with [PEP-612](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/) `ParamcSpec` and `Concatenate`.

```py
from functools import wraps
from typing import Callable, ParamSpec, TypeVar, Concatenate


P1 = ParamSpec("P1")
P2 = ParamSpec("P2")
RT1 = TypeVar("RT1")
RT2 = TypeVar("RT2")


def outer(
    F: Callable[P1, RT1]
) -> Callable[[Callable[Concatenate[RT1, P1], RT2]], Callable[P1, RT2]]:
    def inner(M: Callable[Concatenate[RT1, P1], RT2]) -> Callable[P1, RT2]:
        @wraps(M)
        def aux(*args: P1.args, **kwargs: P1.kwargs) -> RT2:
            res_F = F(*args)
            res_M = M(res_F, *args)
            return res_M

        return aux

    return inner


def some_function(s: str, t: str) -> tuple[int, int]:
    return (len(s), len(t))


@outer(some_function)
def some_method(x_y: tuple[int, int], s: str, t: str) -> None:
    x, y = x_y
    assert len(s) == x
    assert len(t) == y


some_method("foo", "bar")
```

This is a correctly typed code according to [**pyright**](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright). [**mypy**](https://github.com/python/mypy) doesn't support [PEP-612](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/) yet.

To make it work in a general case I had to change some things:

- the injected F's result is the first argument since `ParamSpec` has to be the last argument to `Concatenate`.
- as there is no way to *unpack* the tuple types, the F's result is not unpacked as well.